# Backbone.Marionette - Collection somehow "missing" some elements

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm having this problem which is driving me nuts. I have a collection of entity, named entities which receives A and B objects. The following code, as simple as it may look, does not work as (I) intended.
Somehow the last object being added to the entities collection is not being added. In fact if I print the lengths before and after I get something like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 instead of the expected 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
A and B are "subclasses" of Entity which is a model, being that both A and B have their corresponding views. In the end I'm expecting 6 visible objects but I only get 5.
Has anyone got any idea of what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

```
var that = this;
_.each( this.as.models, function( a, i ){
      that.entities.add( a );
});
_.each( this.bs.models, function( b, j ){
    that.entities.add( b );
});
```

Comment: Could it be that you have the same id for two objects in `this.as.models` and `this.bs.models`?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much. This was stupid on my part. I had previously checked for that but back then it wasn't a problem. Then I changed some code and now I happened to have matching IDs but never remembered to check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add objects or Backbone models to a Backbone collection a check is made to find whether that object is not already present in the collection. In case an existing object is inserted nothing is changed, no events are fired and so on. An object is considered the same either by equality or by matching `id` attributes.

There is a way to override this by passing the `{merge: true}` option to the `add` method.